# Bounding the fourier coefficient field

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Let $f = \sum_n a_n q^n \in S_2(\Gamma_0(N))$ be a normalized, non-CM, newform of weight $N \geq 1$ and level $2$. Let $K_f := {\mathbb Q}(\{a_n\}) \subset {\mathbb C}$ be the number field generated by its Fourier coefficients.

I was wondering if there is a bound known for the discriminant $\Delta_{K_f}$ of $K_f$, in terms of $N$ and (possibly) the dimension of the field $K_f$?

It is okay if this would be a terrible bound. I just need "any" bound.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an *approach* for a **really** **bad** bound.

**Updated below** based on comments and further reflection, but still giving a very bad bound.

1. First, $K_f$ is contained in the field generated by the eigenvalues of the Hecke operators $T_1$, ..., $T_m$, where $m$ is given by Sturm's bound.
2. Using Deligne's bounds on the size of the Hecke eigenvalues of $T_n$, one can bound the discriminant of the number field $K_n$ obtained by adjoining all eigenvalues of $T_n$ to $\mathbb Q$.
3. Now you can use those discriminant bounds to bound the discriminant of the compositum number field $K = K_2 K_3 \dots K_m$, which gives a bound on the discriminant of $K_f$.

This will give a bound that grows much faster than expontially in $N$.

Comment: I see your REALLY bad bound and raise you the following REALLY REALLY bad bound!!! (Actually I haven’t sit and thought about how they compare but anyways :p.) Apply the Masser-Wüstholz endomorphism estimate (https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN266833020_0215) to $J_0(N)$!

Comment: But, in all (well at least slightly more) seriousness, why not just use purity to bound the coefficients of the characteristic polynomials of the $T_n$ (and thus their discriminants)? [Perhaps relevant note: implicitly I’m restricting to $(n,N) = 1$, perhaps by taking a slightly larger $m$.] Is the quaternion algebra argument sharper?

Comment: @alpoge I guess by purity you mean use the Weil (Deligne) bound, yes?  E.g., for $T_p$ just consider $p$-Weil polynomials.  This seems more direct.  I've just thought about Brandt matrices a lot recently, so it was the first thing that came to mind---I think both approach will give similar bounds.

Comment: I seem to remember a result or conjecture that $\log(\Delta_{K_f})/N$ is bounded, and experimentally it seems to be always less than $1/3$.